# How to sort files into folders

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

i need CMD / PowerShell commands? for this problem.

i have this files and i want to put him in folders

from :

```
user_EasonX_72090919_p1_title_伝説の花魁 ゆうぎり.jpg
user_EasonX_72176814_p0_title_ルザミーネ.jpg
user_Endsmall敏＠お仕事募集_72147882_p0_title_虞美人.jpg
user_Endsmall敏＠お仕事募集_72147882_p1_title_虞美人.jpg
user_Endsmall敏＠お仕事募集_72147882_p2_title_虞美人.jpg
user_Endsmall敏＠お仕事募集_72147882_p3_title_虞美人.jpg
user_Didi Esmeralda_74172544_p0_title_Emma Frost.jpg
user_Didi Esmeralda_74172544_p1_title_Emma Frost.jpg
```

to :

```
├───EasonX
│       user_EasonX_72090919_p1_title_伝説の花魁 ゆうぎり.jpg
│       user_EasonX_72176814_p0_title_ルザミーネ.jpg
├───Endsmall敏＠お仕事募集
│       user_Endsmall敏＠お仕事募集_72147882_p0_title_虞美人.jpg
│       user_Endsmall敏＠お仕事募集_72147882_p1_title_虞美人.jpg
│       user_Endsmall敏＠お仕事募集_72147882_p2_title_虞美人.jpg
│       user_Endsmall敏＠お仕事募集_72147882_p3_title_虞美人.jpg
│
├───Didi Esmeralda
│       user_Didi Esmeralda_74172544_p0_title_Emma Frost.jpg
│       user_Didi Esmeralda_74172544_p1_title_Emma Frost.jpg
└───
```

the be start sort from (user_) to (_7)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This powershell script gets the jobs done. You have to specify the target directory in the `$path` variable.

```
 $path = "d:\path\to\your\directory"
 Get-ChildItem $path -Filter "user_*" | ForEach-Object  {
    echo $_.Name
    $folderName = $_.Name.Split("_")[1]
    $newPath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath $folderName
    If(-not (Test-Path -Path $newPath)) {
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $path -Name $folderName
    }
    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $newPath
}
```

It can safely be called several times on the same target.

Comment: Thank you so much I've been looking for it 3 months ago You have already saved me

Comment: Can you also answer me on this question https://superuser.com/questions/1385987/merging-folders-with-the-same-name-from-different-location